# How to output the intermediate file after gcc has included all header files for a C program?

Tags: c, gcc

In a typical C program, I break down it into several components:

```
// main.c
#include 'part-a.h'
#include 'part-b.h'

main () {
// ...
}

// part-a.h
#include 'part-c.h'
// ...
```

I want to export the whole project as one file including every dependencies recursively (excluding standard libraries), how could I do that with `gcc`?

Comment: How to what? The verb is missing.

Comment: You accidentally the verb.

Comment: tar cvfj projectdir.tar.bz2 projectdir

Comment: Note that single quotes around the `#include` file name are non-standard.  You can easily get all the headers (including the system headers) included — and macros expanded.  There's no easy way to get non-system headers included but system headers not included, especially not with macros unexpanded.  It's far from impossible to write code to do the job, but it isn't standard.

Comment: @Axel, output is also a verb: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/output_2

Comment: Yes, I know that. But you can deduce from the two comments above that it was missing when the question was asked in 2013... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc -E` plus all the other option you normally use to compile, without `-c`. This will produce preprocessor output. It's the best you can get, AFAIK there's no way to only expand `#include` directives. But you can use some preprocessor library (GCC and Boost have ones) to write your own tool.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/wave/