# Include of stdint.h in a header file breaks compiling with clock_gettime()

Tags: c, gcc, posix, stdint

My C file uses `clock_gettime()`. For this to work it includes `<time.h>` and defines `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `(200112L)`, as per the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <time.h>

       int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);

       int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);

       int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);

       Link with -lrt (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

   Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       clock_getres(), clock_gettime(), clock_settime():
              _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
```

I compile and link with the following options:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c99 -include $(PROJ_SETTINGS_INC) -lrt
```

, and `PROJ_SETTINGS_INC` is set to an h file that contains settings.

So far, no problem.

Now I modify my settings file and use `uint16_t`, so I include `<stdint.h>` in the settings h file.

The compiler now complains that `clock_gettime()` is an implicit declaration.

If I change back my settings file to use `int` instead of `uint16_t`, and remove the include to `<stdint.h>`, then compiling works again.

Why does including `<stdint.h>` in my settings h file break compiling with `clock_gettime()`?

My best guess is that `stdint` redefines the `POSIX` define, but that does not make sense to me, since the `-include` directive works as if the include was done in the first line of the source.

---

Here is an example (in the light of John Bollinger's answer, I start to understand what is going wrong, but I thought I'd write this anyway).

bar.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct s {
    uint16_t a;
};
```

foo.c

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (199309L)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct s s;
    struct timespec now;

    s.a = 42;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

    printf("answer: %d, time: %lld\n", s.a, (long long) now.tv_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

Build with:

```
gcc foo.c -include bar.h
```

Strangely, this gives a useful warning. In my original application I only got the implicit declaration error.

```
foo.c:1:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (199309L)
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdint.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from ./bar.h:1,
                 from <command-line>:1:
/usr/include/features.h:230:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

Comment: It may be necessary to put #define before **all** #include's.

Comment: Looking at the preprocessor output will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443520/how-to-output-the-intermediate-file-after-gcc-has-included-all-header-files-for/19443632#19443632

Comment: Can you show the content of `$(PROJ_SETTINGS_INC)` file?

Comment: A minimal working example would help. I am failing to reproduce the issue with info provided.

Comment: Where exactly do you define _POSIX_C_SOURCE?

Comment: @rici: it is (was) at the top of the C file, before all includes (but after gcc's `-include`). @ouah, @eugene-sh : updated with source.

Comment: Another thing you need to understand with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is that the presence of this macro causes a conforming implementation of the C language to hide all symbols that are not part of POSIX from the headers mentioned in POSIX. It can be quite a lot of pain to get stuff working correctly when you want to use non-POSIX features in only a few files.

Comment: @FUZxxl: interesting. I started defining the macro when I needed `nanosleep`, not because I wanted portability. Is there another way than defining the macros? I suppose this might have to do with my using `-std=c99`.

Comment: @Gauthier That's a design failure of the glibc. It boggles my mind why they don't supply `nanosleep` without you defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rici pointed out, POSIX requires that (re)definitions of any of the feature test macros it specifies precede inclusion of any of the headers it specifies, including by other header files, else behavior is undefined.  The `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro is such a feature-test macro, and `stdint.h` and `time.h` are both such headers.

In your particular case, the GNU C library's `stdint.h` header and many others rely on a common internal header (`features.h`) that checks which features are explicitly enabled and sets all the feature macros to consistent values (inasmuch as that is possible).  It may both check the value of the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro and set it if it was not already set.  It uses a standard guard macro to avoid being processed multiple times.  Therefore, if a feature macro is redefined later then you risk inconsistent feature definitions.

I have not traced down the exact chain of definitions and redefinitions that causes `clock_gettime()` to fail to be declared in your particular case (and indeed, you have not presented enough information for me to do so), but if you are going to define feature macros then you should ensure that *all* headers see those definitions.  They should appear in your source file before any `#include` directives, and you should avoid otherwise causing any system headers to be preprocessed before those definitions (e.g. via a directive in the file named in your `-include` option).

Note, too, that although we're discussing implementation details, there is no reason to suppose that GNU's implementation is unusual in this respect.  Others will be implemented somewhat differently, but it is *always* wise to ensure that all headers see a consistent set of definitions for any macros that affect them.  Even for macros that are not specified by POSIX.

Comment: It's not just advisable. It's mandatory. Defining a Posix feature test macro after #include of a Posix-specified header (which includes the standard library headers) is undefined behaviour. See the third paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02

Comment: Thanks, @rici. I have updated my answer to call specific attention to the POSIX specifications, and to place the rest of the answer in that context.

Comment: Yes, correct! It doesn't look like you needed more info to pinpoint the issue, but I edited my question with code anyway, thanks. As a follow-up, I am not sure what the best way to use `clock_gettime` is. I still want to include a file from the build command (to be able to build with different files, with `PROJ_SETTINGS_INC=my_file.h make`), but if this file needs `stdint.h` I'm in trouble. What's the generic solution to this, this must happen often? Should I define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` in the `CFLAGS` with `-D`?

Comment: @Gauthier: I find it easiest to put the _POSIX_C_SOURCE define in my CFLAGS, since that guarantees that it is defined before any includes; by adding it to my makefile, I avoid having to think about it again. There's no reason not to use a feature test macro unless you are relying on some deprecated behaviour.

Comment: @Gauthier: if correct compilation of your source depends on a particular value of a standard feature test macro, then I don't understand why you would want to define that macro anywhere other than *in your source*.  Questions of convenience are secondary; placement of the macro definition is a question of *correctness*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I'm not sure I understand. You would not defined the macro in the compilation command? Correct build depends on libs, lib path, include path, and these you put in your makefile, so why not the macro? If you would define the macro in the c file, then I suppose you wouldn't include the settings.h file in the build command either. Then how would you select different settings files?

Comment: @Gauthier, yes, I would put the macro definition in the source file(s), not in the compilation command.  I would do so because it is logically part of the source itself: there is only one value that such a macro may take for the source to be interpreted as intended.  This is different from compilation options that are necessary for building your program, but depend on the build environment, such as lib and include paths and the names of needed external libraries.

Comment: @Gauthier, I don't particularly care for using compiler options to designate additional headers to include, no, but that's not so much an issue if headers so designated provide only *optional* macro definitions and/or define values corresponding to build-time configuration choices (install paths, for example).  I prefer, though, to use an ordinary `#include` for that, possibly guarded by a conditional compilation directive.